# Dapper Stored procedure and View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dapper

I am new in ASP.net MVC (I am using asp 5 mvc 6)

So I want to use stored procedures and I found that Dapper-dot-net is solution.

I created model that stored procedure returns

```
    namespace WebCMS.Dapper
   {
    public class ArticleGetAll
    {
        public int ArticleID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Cotent { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And I created .cs file for commands

```
    public class ArticleAccess
   {
    private IDbConnection db = Connection.GetConnection();

    public List<ArticleGetAll> GetAll()
    {
        string procedureName = "usp_ArticleGetAll";
        return db.Query<ArticleGetAll>(procedureName).ToList();

    }
}
```

And I wanted to create VIEW from model, I get this error
[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TufSW.png)

And how DbContext need to look? Do I need DbContext for Dapper?

I have class Connection.cs that I use to open SQL Connection

```
    namespace WebCMS.Dapper
{
    public class Connection
    {
        public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();

            return con;
        }
    }
}
```

Should I put :DbContext in this class and add DB Sets?

Comment: Dapper does not need DbContext ! Why you are mixing EF with Dapper ?

Comment: Not related, but a Connection variable should be local to the method where you use it and enclosed in a using statement

Comment: Steve Ok thx on advice
@Shyju So I need create view without this generator then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check Dapper documentation for [stored procedures](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#stored-procedures) then you will see that they are using argument `commandType` for that:

```
var user = cnn.Query<User>("spGetUser", new {Id = 1}, 
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();
```

I think this should solve your problem. The error message is very strange, because `DbContext` is not related to Dapper in any way.

Comment: I think the error message is just one of the VS IDE plugins having a hissy fit; nothing whatsoever to do with dapper

Comment: I put that command , but I cant add view :/ I tried to add/remove Dapper but it doesn't work -.-

Comment: What do you mean by "add view"?